# How do I get the Athlete tonic?

Tags: yooka-laylee

While Vendi the Play Tonic distributor has descriptions for each of the tonics, one of the last ones—Athlete—has the following description: "You're gonna have to figure this one out yourself." Well, Yookapedia doesn't have it up yet. How do I unlock the Athlete tonic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Athlete unlocks after **completing the game** (final boss). It extends your power bar. I was still missing one [Power Extender](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vMJHh7FbWE8) by the time I finished, so that isn't a requirement.

Comment: That's a theory I read on [this website](http://tankwarroom.com/article/713/yooka-laylee-how-to-unlock-all-tonics) too, but someone in the comment section seemed to say it didn't unlock the tonic for him. So there might be something else at least.

Answer (score 0):

Basically from what I have been able to find out, you pretty much need to collect everything in the game: the 145 [Pagies](http://yooka-laylee.wikia.com/wiki/Pagie) (and so all the [Ghost Writers](http://yooka-laylee.wikia.com/wiki/Ghost_Writers)), the 1010 [Quills](http://yooka-laylee.wikia.com/wiki/Quill) and all the Health and Power extenders. You will also need to find all the Pirate Treasures hidden in the game. If you didn't find them yet, [this guide](http://tankwarroom.com/article/700/yooka-laylee-all-pirate-treasure-locations) can help you to figure their location. Do note that you also need to beat the game to unlock the tonic.